# Integrate WordPress in Yii

Tags: php

I'm developing a web application in Yii, now the client wants to integrate WordPress in it so he can manage contents on his own.

So how can I integrate WordPress in Yii?

Comment: Hi Maulik. Did you find the answer of this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Yii, but looking at [their Wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/?tag=wordpress) there are already some solutions:

1. [Integrating Wordpress and Yii,Working Out The Details.](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/382/integrating-wordpress-and-yii-working-out-the-details/)
2. [Integrating Wordpress and Yii: still another approach, using Yii as the router/controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/322/integrating-wordpress-and-yii-still-another-approach-using-yii-as-the-router-controller/)
3. [Integrating Wordpress and Yii: yet another approach](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/213/integrating-wordpress-and-yii-yet-another-approach/)
4. [Integrating Yii with Wordpress](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/202/integrating-yii-with-wordpress/)
5. [Run an Yii Application inside an Wordpress page](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/144/run-an-yii-application-inside-an-wordpress-page/)

Please take a look at the above 5 links, they probably contain a suitable solution for you.

Comment: Please don't use lmgtfy links, they are considered poor etiquette at Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: But it uses the header / footer of WordPress and content of YII but i won't to do reverse of it.